# UncaughtError doesn't work in ActionScript worker

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, worker

I want to catch the uncaught error in worker swf. I make a small example:

**Main.as:**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 彩月葵☆彡
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source="/../libs/BackgroundWorker.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static const WORKER:Class;

        private var bWorker:Worker;

        public function Main() 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            bWorker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(new WORKER());
            bWorker.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**BackgroundWorker.as:**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.UncaughtErrorEvent;

    /**
     * @mxmlc -debug -noplay -output libs/BackgroundWorker.swf
     * @author 彩月葵☆彡
     */
    public class BackgroundWorker extends Sprite 
    {
        public function BackgroundWorker() 
        {
            loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);

            throw new Error('an uncaught error');
        }

        private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void 
        {
            trace(e.error.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

The handler won't dispatch. I wonder whether there is something wrong in my code or worker doesn't support UncaughtErrorEvent. If it doesn't, is there a walkaround?

Comment: a worker can't deal this this type of things, only the main app can.

Comment: Yeah so far every time I've used workers they are a huge pain to debug. Even `trace` actions don't get back to the main thread. I usually setup a "debug" message channel that I can easily turn on and off which reports all sorts of debugging information.

Comment: @Aaron In FlashDevelop 4.7 or above, it is able to debug workers. `trace()` and breakpoints work normally.

Comment: That's good to know. With a Flash IDE project or it must compile the SWFs?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with Flash IDE project in Flashdevelop.